# How to find datetime difference in two FrozenTime object

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2  FrozenTime object format and  How can i find the difference of those two

```
Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
(
    [time] => 2016-12-27T10:58:11+00:00
    [timezone] => UTC
    [fixedNowTime] => 
)
```

Another is

```
Cake\I18n\Time Object
(
    [time] => 2016-12-26T11:35:03+00:00
    [timezone] => UTC
    [fixedNowTime] => 
)
```

I want to get the difference between those two

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string: "2016-12-27T10:58:11+00:00" into different parts and then compare them? "2016","12","27","11","00","00"?

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf bad advice (because string manipulation should be a last resort, not the first thing to do). A frozen time object extends `DateTimeImmutable` - i.e. it's just a datetime object with more functionality.

Comment: _A frozen time object extends DateTimeImmutable - i.e. it's just a datetime object with more functionality._ Well, then look for some documentation.

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf the point was more that if you want to learn how to change a tyre on a honda civic 5 door special edition, learn/look for simply how to change a tyre on a car - for which there will be a vast amount of info.